# Como poder controlar formato incorrecto en web api NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar he realizado una web api que solo me retonar un mensaje , y tiene parametros de entrada que lo tengo en una clase Entidades, a continuación le detallo:

1.Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public string Visualizar([FromBody] Usuarios usuarios)
{
    try
    {
       var result = _contexto.visualizar(usuarios);
       return result;
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
       return ex.message.tostring()
    }

}
```

2. Clase Usuario de la capa entidades tiene los siguiente :

```
public int idusuario {get;set;}

public string nombre {get;set;}

public int edad {get;set;}
```

Funciona correctamente cuando lo he probado, pero como ahora en mi trabajo hay un área de QA que se encarga de validar los servicios, el prueba por el postman pero el donde es `int` lo coloca datos de `string` algo como esto por el postman

```
{
   "idusuario":"Hola Mundo",
   "nombre":"pepe",
   "edad" : "no se"
}
```

y al momento de ejecutar por el postman le sale el siguiente mensaje , y es correcto porque el formato es incorrecto pero el quiere que salga en mi response un string que devuelvo y me dice que mi catch debe controlar eso

```
{
    "idusuario":[
       "the input was not valid."
     ],
    "edad":[
      "the input was not valid."
     ]
}
```

y el me dice si yo pruebo eso me debe votar en tu try catch en tu mensaje pero eso yo no lo puedo controlar ya que ni llama a mi controller para poder controlarlo , alguna sugerencia que me pueda ayudar en controlar?

ya que desea que en string que envió lo controle algo así:

```
{
"mensaje" : "El formato es incorrecto"
}
```

Comment: Lo que podrias hacer es que `Visualizar` espere como request una string con formato json y despues validas, ó podrias investigar cual es la contraparte del `HttpMessageHandler` ó `DelegatingHandler` [enlace 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers), [enlace 2](https://geeks.ms/etomas/2013/02/20/como-hacer-seguros-tus-servicios-webapi/) para net core, Los enlaces que dejo no responderan a tu inconveniente, pero espero te sirva a buscar una solucion.

Comment: Por cierto, tbn puedes proponer que se les brindara una documentacion donde estaran detallados los request y los response, porque desde mi punto de vista lo que el usuario esta haciendo es mandar un request mal construido, Te imaginas tener varios varios controladores con varias acciones en donde cada uno reciba como parametro entidades distinta, y en cada uno de ellos validar propiedad por propiedad.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Es lo que hay que hacer. Nunca pero nunca se puede confiar en un request de ningun tipo. Es muy facil cambiar la llamada desde cualquier navegador.

Comment: @gbianchi exacto y quiero validarlo no se como

Comment: no la tengo tan clara, pero es interesante ya que nunca me lo plantee.. debe ser algo en el middleware que controle estas cosas y de una respuesta estandar. Porque asi como esta, no entra al controller no?

Comment: Creo que viene por aca el tema: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49239629/73749

Comment: Como dide gbianchi, se entrama con la posibilidad de meter nulleables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno despues de 2 días,
aqui esta la solución es la siguiente crear 3 clase la que son las siguiente.
1. ValidationError

```
public class ValidationError
    {
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Field { get; }

        public string Message { get; }

        public ValidationError(string field, string message)
        {
            Field = field != string.Empty ? field : null;
            Message = message;
        }
    }
    public class ValidationResultModel
    {
        public string mensaje { get; }

        public string logApplication { get; }

        public ValidationResultModel(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            mensaje = "Formato Invalido";
            logApplication = "Formato Invalido";

        }
    }
```

2.ValidateModelAttribute

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = new ValidationFailedResult(context.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
```

3.ValidationFailedResult

```
public class ValidationFailedResult : ObjectResult
    {
        public ValidationFailedResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        : base(new ValidationResultModel(modelState))
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity;
        }

    }
```

En el controller al comienzo colocar esto: [ValidateModel]

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    **[ValidateModel]**
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
```

y en el startup.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; // This is the setting
            });
        }
```

Seria todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para .Net core puedes hacer un Bindinng personalizado:

Definiendo la clase usuario se especifica un 
Binding personalizado.

```
   [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(UsuarioModelBinder))]
    public class Usuario
    {
        public string  Nombre { get; set; }

        public string Apellidos { get; set; }

        public int Edad { get; set; }

    }
```

La definicion del Binding:

```
 public class UsuarioModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }

           var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

           var edadValue=  bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Edad");
           var nombreValue= bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Nombre");
           var apellidosValue= bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Apellidos");

          int edad = 0;
           if (!int.TryParse(edadValue.ToString(), out edad))
           {

               bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                   "Edad",
                   "La edad debe ser un Entero.");
               return Task.CompletedTask;
           }

           var usuario = new Usuario()
                              {
                                  Edad = edad,
                                  Nombre = nombreValue.ToString(),
                                  Apellidos = apellidosValue.ToString()
                              };

           bindingContext.Result=ModelBindingResult.Success(usuario);

           return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Como puedes ver los errores de validacion simplemente se agregan a la validacion del modelo, para Apellido y nombre no agregue valicion asi que simplemente se pasa el valor.

```
 bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                   "Edad",
                   "La edad debe ser un Entero.");
```

Una vez definidas tus reglas solo falta agregarlo a la configuracion, primero se define el provider:

```
 public class UsuarioBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Usuario))
            {
                return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(UsuarioModelBinder));
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

y este se agrega al inicio en la configuracion, en la clase Startup se agrega el provider:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddMvc(opts =>
                    {
                        opts.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new UsuarioBinderProvider());
                    });
        }
```

En el controlador se devuelven los campos invalidos en caso de haberlos,

```
[HttpPost("Registrar")]
        public IActionResult Registrar([FromBody] Usuario nuevoUsuario)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }


                //Todo: aqui el registro de usuario

                return this.Ok();
       }
```

Haciendo una prueba con la edad como cadena se obtiene:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso te puede servir para marcar el campo erroneo en el la vista de Registro
Saludos.